# What's the difference between acceptance region and confidence interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, interpretation

I know that the **confidence interval** is part of the parameter space, whereas the **acceptance region** is part of the sample space. We do hypothesis testing once, we get a acceptance region and a accepted/rejected hypothetical parameter value. We repeatedly do hypothesis testing to get enormous accepted hypothesis, which constitute a interval covering the true parameter value with 0.95 probability. But I still feel confused about these two concepts. Thanks for your favor and patience.